# Bluetooth no sound transfer

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

My PC recognises Bluetooth speakers and headphones and shows them as connected, but the sound still comes through the PC rather than speakers or headphones.
Using Windows 10 on a HP computer, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that you have to select either BT-speakers or BT-headphones as playback device in the windows audio preferences. The builtin laptop-speakers might still be the default.

> ... and shows them as connected, ...

refers to being connected via bluetooth only. I don't think the default device changes automatically.